# How to get content of XML files using foreach loop in PowerShell?

Tags: xml, powershell, foreach

I want to display the content of all the XML files present in a folder one by one.
Commands I am using are:

```
$test = Get-ChildItem | Select-Object -Property Name
foreach ($i in $test) {
    Get-Content $i
}
```

but it is not working as expected. 
It is throwing an error saying:

> Cannot find path \<dir_path>\@{Name=<filename>.xml} because it does not exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get-Content is wildcard aware so you can display them with simply:

```
Get-Content *.xml
```

If you want to perform a more complex action or perhaps separate them you could use something like:

```
Get-ChildItem *.xml -file | ForEach-Object { 
  Write-Warning ("`n    $($_.FullName) `n" + '=' * 72)
  Get-Content $_.fullName
}
```

This is just an example of what you might do to separate the files visually or perform any other action -- you could stop and wait for a keypress etc....